# git - replicating local repository from machine1 to machine2

Tags: git, github

Currently, I have `machine1` where the directory structure is thus:

```
c:\myprojects\project1\
c:\myprojects\project2\
```

Both directories had multiple files within themselves respectively. Only the `\project1\` folder is stored in github via:

```
Navigate to c:\myprojects\ on machine1. Open command prompt.
git init
git add c:\myprojects\project1
git commit -m "Commit project1"
git branch -M master
git remote add origin https://github.com/Tryer/myprojects.git
git push -u origin master
```

`\project2\` is not under source control.

Thus, on `machine1` under `c:\myprojects\` there is a `.git\` folder created.

All of my data under `c:\myprojects\` (subfolders `\project1\`, `\project2` and `\.git\`) is automatically backed up in the cloud via google drive.

Now, soon, I plan to replace `machine1` (stop using it completely) and migrate my work to a completely different `machine2`. On this new `machine2`, I first plan to sync all data from the cloud on a *different* path (say under `e:\` instead of `c:\`). For e.g., I will have on `machine2` the following directory structure after syncing.

```
e:\myprojects\project1
e:\myprojects\project2
e:\myprojects\.git
```

After this sync, can I continue to use `git` as if nothing changed? In other words, the question is, is there any data/metadata in the `.git` folder that is specific to `machine1`? (If there is such machine specific data, how can I change that to correspond to `machine2`?) For instance, suppose I now decide to add `\project2\` to source control, can I just do:

```
git add e:\myprojects\projects //note e:\ here and not c:\, since this is happening on machine2
git commit -m "Commit project2"
git branch -M master
git push -u origin master
```

as I would have done under `machine1` (except on `machine1` I would use `c:\` instead of `e:\`)?

Comment: Did you read the documentation and tutorials for [git](https://git-scm.com/) ? It is online and written in English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use git as though nothing has changed.

I think what you're trying to achieve can also be done completely using git and github instead of google drive, if you don't mind project 2 being in source control:

- add project 1 and project 2 to source control, and push up to GitHub
- On your new PC inside your new directory, do `git clone <url of remote repository>`

Comment: Thanks, my worry was changing of machines would cause some time consuming / repetition because the `.git` folder is created afresh, etc. or if it had something specific from `machine1` stored inside of it. I therefore suppose the folder only stores relative addresses. For some other reason (`\myprojects` folder is rather large and contains numerous other stuff that does not belong in an online source control system) I prefer using google drive.